# what does read-only means?

Tags: c, memory, ram

i was reading  some topics when i found this  code and the first comment  says

> stored in a read-only memory area

What does that mean ?how do i  know if the string or variable is read-only ?

```
char *p = "wikipedia"; // stored in a read-only memory area valid C, deprecated in C++98/C++03, ill-formed as of C++11
p[0] = 'W'; // undefined behavior
```

Comment: There's no way to know. You should declare `const char *p` if it will only be used to point to the literal.

Comment: The [C11 Standard 6.4.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5) says: "*... If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.*" It's not *read-only* per se, it's a mnemonic for human programmers; on some implementation it may be modifiable... and, **for that implementation** the behaviour is no longer undefined (provided the feature is documented).

Answer (score 0):

The string "wikipedia" is read-only because it is a literal constant declared in your code.

`*p` is a pointer, and the memory it is pointing to contains your string "wikipedia". Because that memory is allocated using the apparently deprecated method of assigning a string directly to a pointer, it is read-only.

If you want it to be not read-only, allocate the memory on the stack or the heap. (For example, by using `malloc`)

Comment: "Deprecated" refers to assigning a string literal to a *non-`const`* pointer. `char const *p = "bla";` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: "Deprecated" is also referring to C++ standards only.

Comment: but i think if i allocate a pointer in heap using malloc i can read and write from it for example :    `char *str = malloc(5*sizeof(char));  str[0] = 'x';` ?

Comment: should i learn assembly to understand this low level stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

`"wikipedia"` it is called the string literal. It does not have to be stored in read-only memory.  Standard says that string literals cannot be modified, and if you try to modify one invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

```
char *p = "Wikipedia";
```

defines pointer `p` which holds the reference (address) of the string literal "Wikipedia".

If you want to modify that string you need to define a `char` array:

```
char p[] = "Wikipedia";
```